# Vaadin - Iterate over components in a layout

Tags: layout, dynamic, iterator, components, vaadin

I'm working on a project in Vaadin 7. In that I need to parse over all the components in a Layout and find a component I need.

[image]

The above is the pictorial representation of my layout.

I'm dynamically creating the green coloured Vertical layout inside blue coloured Vertical layout. Since I'm creating them dynamically, I can't have any instance for those dynamically created things. But, I have unique ID's for all the components.

Now I need to find a Combobox using the Id. I donno how to parse in to the combobox from the Blue coloured vertical layout.

All I have is an instance of the blue coloured vertical layout and Id's for combobox.
And, I can have ID's for green and red layouts too if needed.

I need something like this, But stuck..

```
Iterator<Component> iterate = blueMainLayout.iterator();
Combobox cb;
while (iterate.hasNext()) {
Component c = (Component) iterate.next();
cb = (Combobox) blueMainLayout.....;
        if (cb.getId().equals(something.getId())) {
            // do my job
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would it be a idea to put all the components you will need later on in hashset and use the ID as the key ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to check component recursively.

```
class FindComponent {
    public Component findById(HasComponents root, String id) {
        System.out.println("findById called on " + root);

        Iterator<Component> iterate = root.iterator();
        while (iterate.hasNext()) {
            Component c = iterate.next();
            if (id.equals(c.getId())) {
                return c;
            }
            if (c instanceof HasComponents) {
                Component cc = findById((HasComponents) c, id);
                if (cc != null)
                    return cc;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}

FindComponent fc = new FindComponent();
Component myComponent = fc.findById(blueMainLayout, "azerty");
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Though using `HasComponents.iterator()` is still possible [`com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponentContainer`](https://www.vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponentContainer.html) implements `java.lang.Iterable<Component>`, which makes the iteration a bit more comfortable:

```
  ...
  for ( Component c : layout ) {
    if ( id.equals( c.getId() ) ) {
      return c;
    }
  }
  ...
```